# find uitableviewcell which is swiped / in editing mode

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6

I've added a UITableView into my app. This tableview includes cells, which shows a few custom editing buttons if they're swiped to the left (via this function: editActionsForRowAtIndexPath). I'd like to find out which UITableViewCell is swiped to the left or shows up the custom editing options and set a default text as a detailText label into this cell.

For further explanation:

I have a few UITableViewCells. The user swipes one of these cells. Now the cell is in the editing mode and shows the editing option, which I've added (named "Date"). The user press this button/option (Date). Now a datePicker is poping up. The user chose a date. This date is written in a label. This dateLabel should be transmitted into the detailTextLabel of the cell which was swiped. The problem is that I don't know how to transmit the label with the date to the detailTextLabel of the cell which was swiped.

I hope someone can help me. I am coding with Swift.

This is my code for the custom options if the UITableViewCell is swiped to the left:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {

  let editingCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

  let date = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Date", handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in

  self.showSideBar(true)
  self.delegate?.sideBarWillOpen?()
  self.isEditingStyle = true

  })

  date.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.204, green:0.667, blue:0.863, alpha: 1.0);

  return [date];
}
```

date picker:

```
    func datePickerChanged(datePicker:UIDatePicker) {

    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle

    var strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
    dateLabel.text = strDate

}
```

adding date into detailTextLabel:

```
        lastEditedCell?.detailTextLabel?.text = dateLabel
```

Comment: Keep track of the swiped cell with a reference in your viewController:

`weak var lastCellEdited:UITableViewCell?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep track of the lastEditedCell in `tableView(tableView:, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:)` function

```
var lastEditedCell:UITableViewCell? // property of the class

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {

  let editingCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

   lastEditedCell = editingCell
   //Your Code

}
```

After you set the date from picker view, you can set in the callback function.

```
lastEditedCell?.detailTextLabel.text = date
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I implemented the code into my project. But it's not possible to set the date var (dateLabel) as the text of detailTextLabel. I posted some code in my question. May it helps you for better understanding. Do you also have a solution for this?

Comment: You can't replace the label. Set the text property of the detailTextLabel as date string or datelabel.text